# Unable to locate an element even when the xpath is correct

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

i'm tried to select an element from an auto suggestion field but i got always an error saying that the element could not be found even that i'm sure my xpath is correct

here's my code :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"ui-menu-item-with-icon ui-menu-item\"][1]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"ui-menu-item-with-icon ui-menu-item\"][1]")).click();
```

it should find //*[@class=\"ui-menu-item-with-icon ui-menu-item\"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu4eq.jpg) which is the first suggestion albert cammus

here's the outerHtml

```
<li class="ui-menu-item-with-icon ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
  <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
    <span class="item-icon"></span>
    Albert Camus (SARCELLES)</a>
</li>"
```

Comment: could you just use By.className instead of xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is more or less OK apart from using wildcard which may result into longer processing so you can go for `li` instead of `*`.

Another option is sticking to the [`<a>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)  [containing the text](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55281024) you would like to click using [normalize-space() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) something like:

```
//a[normalize-space()="Albert Camus (SARCELLES)"]
```

[image]

Also your popup may reside within an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) so you might have to [switch the webdriver context](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-iframes-using-selenium-webdriver/) to the relevant iframe element.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try linkText over Xpath ?

linkText is more stable then Xpath, there's no doubt about that.

**Code :**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Albert Camus (SARCELLES)")));
```

I'm not very sure about spaces in your HTML, that's the reason why I have used **partialLinkText**